# Jigsaw Puzzle Solver Method

Tags: java, algorithm, puzzle

Ok, so I have a 3 x 3 jig saw puzzle game that I am writing and I am stuck on the solution method.

```
public Piece[][] solve(int r, int c) {
    if (isSolved())
        return board;
    board[r][c] = null;
    for (Piece p : pieces) {
        if (tryInsert(p, r, c)) {
            pieces.remove(p);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (getPieceAt(r, c) != null)
        return solve(nextLoc(r, c).x, nextLoc(r, c).y);
    else {
        pieces.add(getPieceAt(prevLoc(r, c).x, prevLoc(r, c).y));
        return solve(prevLoc(r, c).x, prevLoc(r, c).y);
    }
}
```

I know I haven't provided much info on the puzzle, but my algorithm should work regardless of the specifics. I've tested all helper methods, pieces is a List of all the unused Pieces, tryInsert attempts to insert the piece in all possible orientations, and if the piece can be inserted, it will be. Unfortunately, when I test it, I get StackOverflow Error.

Comment: What exactly is `prev` supposed to do? Does it store only the last arrangement? Also, how many messages are printed?

Comment: `prev` is supposed to store the first Piece used in an incorrect combination for a certain location: so when I have to back one location, I store the Piece that was used there so I don't try to use it again. Since I add that Piece back to the end of `pieces`, if I hit prev[r][c], I know I need to go back another location. As for how many messages are printed: far too many to count. (I hope my explanation of `prev` made any sense)

Comment: A "StackOverflow" is caused when you make too many method calls.  Each method causes a new block to be put on the execution "stack".  This is seen when you print the stack trace on an exception...it is literally printing the execution stack for that thread.  Most often than not, this is a problem with infinite recursion, which is looks like you are using.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `break` command from `if (p.equals(prev[r][c]))`? It's possible that it prevents the correct puzzle insertion and then the code gets to infinite recursion.

Comment: I tried removing prev all together, but i get StackOverflow again...still not sure whats going wrong.

Comment: There are lots of reasons outside the code you've provided that would cause the error.  What does `tryInsert` look like, for example?

Comment: do you ever update things so that `isSolved()` can return true?

Comment: By the way, a line like `return solve(nextLoc(r, c).x, nextLoc(r, c).y);` means method `nextLoc` is executed twice - with the same parameters. You should eliminate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to structure your recursion differently. I'm also not sure adding and removing pieces from different places of the list is safe; much as I'd rather avoid allocation in the recursion it might be safest to create a list copy, or scan the board
so far for instances of the same piece to avoid re-use.

```
public Piece[][] solve(int r, int c, List<Piece> piecesLeft) {
    // Note that this check is equivalent to
    // 'have r and c gone past the last square on the board?'
    // or 'are there no pieces left?'
    if (isSolved())
        return board;

    // Try each remaining piece in this square
    for (Piece p : piecesLeft) {
        // in each rotation
        for(int orientation = 0; orientation < 4; ++orientation) {
            if (tryInsert(p, r, c, orientation)) {
                // It fits: recurse to try the next square
                // Create the new list of pieces left
                List<Piece> piecesLeft2 = new ArrayList<Piece>(piecesLeft);
                piecesLeft2.remove(p);
                // (can stop here and return success if piecesLeft2 is empty)
                // Find the next point
                Point next = nextLoc(r, c);
                // (could also stop here if this is past end of board)

                // Recurse to try next square
                Piece[][] solution = solve(next.x, next.y, piecesLeft2);
                if (solution != null) {
                    // This sequence worked - success!
                    return solution;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // no solution with this piece
    return null;
}
```

Comment: somehow, this code always returns null. Was I supposed to do something with this code? or was it meant to be the solution? For the most part, it makes sense to me, I'm just a bit confused with the part that says if (solution != null) return solution; Shouldn't it return the board if it is solved anyway?

Comment: I can't promise I've got this exactly right but that's the pattern I'd use. It returns null at each level if it can't find a solution, so it'll return null overall if it can't find one at all. Perhaps I've made a mistake. The != null part: this means if the recursive call didn't return null, i.e. it was solved, then return what it returned else continue searching. You're right this will be board in your case - it's more testing the return value of the child recursion. Perhaps try debugging a simpler 2x2 case you can solve on paper?

Comment: actually, it was a really simple fix, after every iteration I just needed to clear the board starting at whatever location it was currently at, so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your DFS-style solution algorithm never re-adds Piece objects to the `pieces` variable.  This is not sound, and can easily lead to infinite recursion.

Suppose, for example, that you have a simple 2-piece puzzle, a 2x1 grid, where the only valid arrangement of pieces is [2, 1].  This is what your algorithm does:

1) Put piece 1 in slot 1
  2) It fits!  Remove this piece, pieces now = {2}.  Solve on nextLoc()
     3) Now try to fit piece 2 in slot 2... doesn't work
     4) Solve on prevLoc()
        5) Put piece 2 in slot 1
        6) It fits!  Remove this piece, pieces is now empty.  Solve on nextLoc()
           7) No pieces to try, so we fail.  Solve on prevLoc()
              8) No pieces to try, so we fail.  Solve on prevLoc()
                9) No pieces to try, so we fail.  Solve on prevLoc()
                   Repeat ad infinitum...

As commenters have mentioned, though, this may only be part of the issue.  A lot of critical code is missing from your post, and their may be errors there as well.

Comment: Good point, I added `pieces.add(getPieceAt(prevLoc(r, c).x, prevLoc(r, c).y));` Also, isSolved() checks to see if the entire board is filled, so that should stop it from going on forever no?

Answer (score 1):

`StackOverflowError` with recursive functions means that you're either lacking a valid recursion stop condition or you're trying to solve too big problem and should try an iterated algorithm instead. Puzzle containing 9 pieces isn't too big problem so the first thing must be the case.

The condition for ending recursion is board completion. You're only trying to insert a piece in the `for` loop, so the problem is probably either that the `tryInsert()` method doesn't insert the piece or it doesn't get invoked. As you're sure that this method works fine, I'd suggest removing `break;` from

```
if (p.equals(prev[r][c])) 
{
    System.out.println("Hello");
    break;
}
```

because it's the only thing that may prevent the piece from being inserted. I'm still unsure if I understand the `prev` role though.